# Find shortest path in undirected graph that goes through all vertices and returns to starting vertex

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

I have an undirected weighted graph like this one

[image]

My task is to find the fastest path (with least weight) that goes from specified vertex goes through all vertices and returns to the starting vertex without repeating a vertex.

```
Graph
1 3 time 5
3 2 time 5
2 4 time 5
4 1 time 5
4 3 time 4
1 2 time 5

Starting vertex 3
Path 1: 3->1->4->2->3
Path 2: 3->2->1->4->3  
Time 1 and 2: 5+5+5+5=20

Path 3: 3->1->2->4->3     
Path 4: 3->4->2->1->3  
Time 3 and 4: 5+5+5+4=19 -> fastest
```

Is there a fastest way than DFS to solve the problem?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: I believe the `3->2->1->4->3` path also has cost 19.

Answer (score -2):

Travelling salesman problem looks almost the same but I can't repeat a visited vertex.

Going from vertex 3 to vertex 5 I can't do that
3 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 3-> 4 -> 3

A solution is: 3->1->2->4->3

That's my function:

```
private static List<HashMap<Integer,Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<>();


public static void dfs(int currentVertex,Stack<Integer> visited,long currentTime) {
    if(visited.size() == graph.size()-1) {
        if(!graph.get(currentVertex).containsKey(targetVertex)) {
            return;
        }

        currentTime += graph.get(currentVertex).get(targetVertex);
        if(currentTime < fastestTime) {
            fastestTime = currentTime;
        }
        return;
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> vertex: graph.get(currentVertex).entrySet()) {
        if(!visited.contains(vertex.getKey())) {
            visited.add(vertex.getKey());
            dfs(vertex.getKey(),visited,currentTime + vertex.getValue());
            visited.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TSP also visits each vertex exactly once.

Comment: What is `entrySet`? What is `vertex.getValue()`? Could you please describe your algorithm by pseudo-code?